# How to add element to other method's list

Tags: c#, list

i want to add item to list from another method. When i describe my list in method, every time it create list again, my aim is add item to list on every call of "write" method. Maybe there can be another solution. My problem is clear.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ZiyaretciDefteriConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<GuestBookItems> _data = new List<GuestBookItems>();
            Write();
            Write();
        }

        static void Write()
        {
            string date = Console.ReadLine();
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            string message = Console.ReadLine();

            _data.Add(new GuestBookItems()
            {
                DateTime = date,
                Name = name,
                Message = message
            });



        }




        public class GuestBookItems
        {
            public string DateTime { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }


    }




}
```

Comment: The code you've provided currently won't compile - `_data` is a local variable within `Main`, so isn't available in `Write`.

Comment: Just read the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/

Comment: Change singatute and pass list to `Write`: `static void Write(List<GuestBookItems> list) {...}`

Comment: Move the declaration of the variable _data to common space. Right not it is inside the method Main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create the list as a class member, so you can access it both in the `main` method and in the `write` method.

In your case, as all your methods are static, instead of a class member you need to use a static field, like so:

```
class Program
{
    static List<GuestBookItems> _data;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _data = new List<GuestBookItems>();
        Write();
        Write();
    }

    static void Write()
    {
        string date = Console.ReadLine();
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        string message = Console.ReadLine();

        _data.Add(new GuestBookItems()
        {
            DateTime = date,
            Name = name,
            Message = message
        });
    }

    public class GuestBookItems
    {
        public string DateTime { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities. If you want to keep `_data` a *local variable*, pass it to `Write`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // _data is a local valiable
        List<GuestBookItems> _data = new List<GuestBookItems>();
        Write(_data); // which we pass to Write in order to add item 
        Write(_data);
    }

    // Write accept list...
    static void Write(List<GuestBookItems> list)
    {
        string date = Console.ReadLine();
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        string message = Console.ReadLine();

        list.Add(new GuestBookItems() // ... to add item to
        {
            DateTime = date,
            Name = name,
            Message = message
        });
    }
```

If you want any method of the class has an access to `_data`, extract it as a *field*:

```
    // _data is a static field
    static List<GuestBookItems> _data = new List<GuestBookItems>(); 
  
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // now we have no need in creation _data
        Write(); // there's no need to pass anything into Write
        Write();
    }

    static void Write()
    {
        string date = Console.ReadLine();
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        string message = Console.ReadLine();

        // take the field (which is known to the method) and modify it
        _data.Add(new GuestBookItems()
        {
            DateTime = date,
            Name = name,
            Message = message
        });
    }
```